# Scaffold existing database using EF Core 6 to extend IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

This might seem like a duplicate question but it is not. When scaffolding an exiting table using EF Core, a dbcontext class will be created that extends DbContext. My database already contains the identity tables(AspNetUser, AspNetRole etc..), so scaffolding it will create models and DbSets for these tables which should not be the case.

Is there a way to scaffold a database and create a dbcontext file that extends IdentityDbContext?

I know I can tell EF Core to ignore these tables but it will create another dbContext class, and even when specifying the already existing dbcontext class that extends IdentityDbContext , it will override it and make it extend DbContext.

Comment: Add a partial class that extends IdentitDbContext

Comment: I usually scaffold to a folder called "EF" or "DB" so the namespace of everything that was scaffold is pretty particular.

Answer (score 2):

I researched the same question some time ago and found that there is no way to do it if you want to keep your current context. The best option I found is to use the scaffold command in a separate test project only for the tables you need and copy everything in your current context. Of course, if you have a lot of tables, this becomes quite slow and tedious. The scaffold in EF is a bit incomplete and not intended for such average situations.